MicroROS error on connecting agent ROS2: device disconnected or multiple access on port?
I'm trying to setup a project in MicroROS to subscribe at /cmd_vel with an ESP32.
When I run the MicroROS agent on my pc on the same port of the ESP32 (/dev/ttyUSB0) I get continuously this error on the serial monitor of the ESP32: "Disconnected (device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?))".
Could be a problem with the DDS? Because I get also this warning for some times when I run the nodes: "[WARN] [1716303904.383064331] [rmw_cyclonedds_cpp]: Failed to parse type hash for topic 'ros_discovery_info' with type 'rmw_dds_common::msg::dds_::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_' from USER_DATA '(null)'.
"

Is your wifi off? Turning off the wifi worked for us but currently we don't know the reason why.
